# Running parallel map job in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have one question.

Suppose I am having one file in HDFS and while reading the file its converted into 4 input splits. Now for all the 4 input splits there would be 4 map task, so my question is these 4 map task can run in parallel by 4 task tracker or it can by run by less than 4 task tracker if those task tracker has slot to run more than one task.

Thanks
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 input splits you would have 4 map tasks. These tasks would be scheduled for execution. If you have MRv1, then they would be scheduled to the tasktrackers. If you have only 1 task tracker with only 1 map slot, then all the 4 tasks would be executed sequentially. But by default the framework will try to start them all in parallel if it is possible. If you have MRv2, then YARN would be responsible for scheduling these tasks and the scheduling will depend on the amount of memory available on the machines running the YARN NodeManagers, but again by default it will try to run them all in parallel

So in general, the framework will do its best to start all the map tasks in parallel. But if it will happend that it does not have enough resources to do so (not enough free map slots in MRv1 or not enough free memory in MRv2) they will run with less parallelism or even sequentially (or even stay in "pending" state if you don't have any resources at all)

Comment: OK Thanks.It means reading the input split is a parallel work and writing the file in HDFS( with multiple block) in sequential manner or it is also a parallel work.

Comment: Reading a single input split is sequential work performed by a single map task. But if the file is split in many input splits, they would be read in parallel by many separate map tasks. Writing an output of a single reduce task is again sequential, but if you have many reducers all of them will write their output in parallel, this is why MR job result is a folder with N files, where N is the number of reducers (or the number of mappers in case of map-only job). `hdfs put` command also works sequentially

Comment: Thanks.One question if we need to place one file of size (1gb) in hdfs and  that file is devided into N number of  blocks, so all these blocks written in parrael in hdfs by data nodes or it will be sequential.

Comment: If you use `hdfs put` they would be written sequentially because of the logic of client application (`hdfs put` itself)

Comment: One question regarding the map reduce of shuffle and sort phase. Which phase happens first (shuffle or sort)?

Comment: Sort then shuffle. Take a look here, it is almost complete description: http://0x0fff.com/hadoop-mapreduce-comprehensive-description/